# Crtl+C not killing server

Tags: node.js, windows, server, windows-10, git-bash

I'm running Windows 10 and when I try to kill the process using Crtl+C it doesn't work and I have to run :

```
netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber
taskkill //PID typeyourPIDhere //F
```

That stops the process and when I run nodemon server restarts fine, but if I have mongod running then nodemon throws port already in use and it crashes.

Edit 1:
I am now able to use nodemon by starting my server through the nodemon command on my git bash (`nodemon app.js`).  This has solved most of my issues, however I still can't close my server through the ctrl+c shortcut, I have to manually kill the server task every time I want to close it or if I make changes to my main file.

Comment: what do you mean by Ctrl+C doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't shut down the server, or it causes my git bash to crash.